How to call area's partial view in area's layout page in ASP.NET MVC using C#?
I created an area with the name of Member in ASP.NET MVC, and also created a partial view with the name of _Header.cshtml in the Member area.
Now I want to call _Header.cshtml partial view in Member area's layout page.
I tried below lines to call Header into Layout page but that is not working.
<partial name="/Member/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml"></partial>
<partial name="../Member/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml"></partial>
<partial name="~/Member/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml"></partial>
<partial name="/Member/_Header.cshtml"></partial>
<partial name="_Header.cshtml"></partial>

Can anyone tell me how to call area's partial view into area's layout page?

If it is a partial in the same area then I believe "_Header.cshtml" should work. Though I recommend using Razor's @await Html.PartialAsync("_Header.cshtml") MVC will look for partial views in the current area/views/view and area/views/shared folders. Normally though the partial views would be referenced in the actual View, not the Layout, that may come into play as well.

Thank you so much dost. It woking now with this line of code @Html.Partial("_Header"). Thank you so much once again.
